# Why doesn't the potential drop as a $E=\nabla V$ inside a circuit when there is no resistor?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, potential, electrical-resistance, batteries

Considering that an electric field exists outside a battery and inside a circuit, shouldn't the potential drop while we move along the wire even if there is no resistor ($E=\nabla V$)?

I am asking this because when I see diagrams of potential along the wire they all show a constant potential along the wire until it reaches a resistor in which the potential drops.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22773/

Answer (score 3):

At equilibrium, the field inside an ideal conductor is zero.  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/gausur.html#c2

A charge moving through such a conductor neither gains nor loses energy.

We can't attach an ideal conductor to an ideal voltage source.  Something has to give.  There will be a voltage drop along a real wire due to non-zero resistance, and there will be a reduction in voltage from the battery that we can attribute to a non-zero internal resistance.    That's assuming neither one bursts into flame from overheating first.

Comment: Is it zero or non-zero and constant?Because i have read that the current auto-correct it self before reaching steady-state where it has electric field non-uniform and when it reaches steady-state the field is uniform but not zero.

Comment: Where have you read this, @Landos Adam? Because BowlofRed is right in the context which he speaks of. Apply Gauss's law of electricity in integral form to obtain the result that the field inside an *ideal* conductor is zero.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102930/why-doesnt-the-electric-field-inside-a-wire-in-a-circuit-fall-off-with-distance

Comment: i think that when you apply gauss law,then the Q enclosed inside the gaussian surface is non-zero.So the electric field is not zero.If the electric field is uniform then the E comes out of the integral of E.dS and then you only have E multiplied by integral of dS and it is equal to Q enclosed/εο.But the key here is that Q enclosed is not zero.

Comment: have you seen the link?

Comment: Yes.  The link shows an ideal battery attached to an ideal conductor.  The system is not at equilibrium.  Rather than constant current, current is increasing.  In a real circuit, charges would rearrange to the point that $E=0$ inside the wire.

Comment: @BowlOfRed So,the link shows the system before reaching its steady-state.But when it finally reaches steady-state,i still do not understand why E=0.Why would they rearrange in a certain way as to give the system E=0?also,this is not electrostatics.Because the link that you posted above point out that E=0 because the charges do not move on the surface.In this situation,the charges DO move.

Comment: In steady state the charges move but the flow of charges is constant and uniform so that it gives the same results as in static case. I gave you the same answer about electric field being 0 inside a conductor in equilibrium on your other question on the same topic yesterday.