# Voltage and Electric Field in a Circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

I have a doubt regarding how the electric field acts in a circuit.

I have been told that a normal cell creates a uniform electric field, but I find it a bit confusing. Let me explain my doubt with a diagram.

[image]

Suppose there is a circuit and the resistor $r_1$ undergoes a potential drop of $0.4~\rm V$ and resistor $r_2$ undergoes a potential drop of $1.1~\rm V$ but then, since the electric field increases with increase in potential gradient, then the electric field through the resistor $r_2$ should be greater, shouldn't it? This goes against the idea that electric field in a circuit is uniform and if the electric field isn't constant in the circuit, then why is the battery called a fixed voltage source if the electric field applied by it varies? I find this very confusing,

Comment: What gave you the idea that electric field in a circuit is uniform? It definitely isn't. Perhaps you're confusing current with electric field?

Comment: since the cell produces a constant electric field, i thought it would be reasonable to assume electric field in a circuit is constant and even in the derivation of ohm's law ,it is taken a constant .

Comment: I don't know what derivation of Ohm's law you're talking about, but I think it's likely that the electric field is taken to be constant across a single component. As for your other point, you've *shown* that the electric field is not uniform in this circuit. The electric field configuration created by a cell depends on the circuit it is connected to, and is not uniform in general.

Comment: so then , both the resistors should be experiencing different electric field ,right ?but since, a 1.5v potential difference is created across the terminals of the cell,an electric field would be  generated which takes the electrons from the postive to negative terminal of the cell . shouldn't that be constant ? if then ,the electric field through the wire ,changes on seeing the resistor and after passing out of the resistor,it gains its constant magnitude .is that how it works ?

Comment: also, why is battery  called a fixed voltage source if electric field supplied by it varies across resistors ?

Comment: "both the resistors should be experiencing different electric field, right?" Right. "shouldn't that be constant?" Why would it be constant? *You* just showed that it's not constant.

Comment: i was talking about the electric field created by the cell to move the electrons from the positive to negative terminal through the conducting wire . i was asking whether that is constant not the E in the resistors (since i understood that they must be different with your help)

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102930/why-doesnt-the-electric-field-inside-a-wire-in-a-circuit-fall-off-with-distance

Answer (score 2):

It is best not to think in terms of fields if you are doing circuits. The primary quantities of interest in circuits are voltage and current. The E field is the spatial derivative of the voltage, eg the units of the E field is V/m. However, in a circuit the position is abstracted away. There is no indication of the length of any wire or resistor or battery. So there is no way to obtain information about the E fields given only information about the circuit theory representation of the circuit.

Inside a resistor the E field should be more or less uniform, with a value approximately equal to the voltage across it divided by its length.

Inside a capacitor the E field should be more or less uniform between the plates and zero within the plates.

Inside a battery the E field should be quite strong right at the electrode where the electrochemical reaction makes the voltage difference occur over molecular-scale distances.  The E-field will be substantially lower elsewhere, including approximately 0 within the metallic conductor and relatively close to 0 within the electrolyte. Calling it uniform is not accurate.

Comment: > *"Inside a resistor the E field should be more or less uniform"* Not for heavy duty resistors that are made of coiled high resistance wire. Only magnitude of electric field is more-or-less the same along that wire.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted, electric field in a circuit in not uniform. This is totally correct. The thing which is uniform is current.

But the total potential drop across the battery is $1.5V$. Even if you add more resistances and make different arrangements from them, the potential drop across the battery remains same. Hence, the Electric field across the *battery* remains constant. For this reason, the battery is called a fixed voltage source, it *maintains* constant potential drop across itself.